# Acessando objetos de um JSON

Tags: php, json, laravel

Eu tenho o seguinte arquivo `.json`, no caso eu quero acessar dado inicial, chamado `suzuki` no começo do json, com faço para pegar essa informação?

Esse `.json` é responsavel por fazer o seed dos dados no banco, e esse campo é o do relacionamento, preciso apenas pegar ele na classe.

Os restante do outros dados eu consigo pegar o valor e salvar no banco.

- Metodo de cadastra a Concessionária.

```
    private function fillDealerships(array $files)
    {
        foreach ($files as $file) {
            $data = $this->getFileContent($file);

            foreach ($data as $item) {
                $slug = isset($data['u']) ? Str::slug($item['slug']) : $file['filename'];

                /* @var $dealership Dealership */
                $dealership = Dealership::query()->firstOrCreate([
                    'slug' => $slug,
                    $dealership->brands()
                ], [
                    'name' => $item['n'] ?? $slug,
                ]);

                $this->fillDealershipStore($dealership, $item);
            }
        }
    }
```

- Json das Lojas da Concessionária.

```
{
  "suzuki": [
    {
      "n": "MOTO MAIS",
      "u": "moto-mais",
      "e": {
        "l": "Av. Oswaldo Da Silva",
        "n": "710",
        "m": "",
        "b": "Conjunto Habitacional Ana Jacinta",
        "u": "19064070",
        "c": {
          "i": "9286",
          "n": "Presidente Prudente"
        },
        "s": {
          "i": "26",
          "n": "Sao Paulo"
        },
        "r": "https:\/\/goo.gl\/maps\/aYoJgneRsTo",
        "g": [
          "-22.1505632",
          "-51.4526682"
        ]
      },
      "c": {
        "t": {
          "c": {
            "n": "(18) 3901-1911",
            "l": "1839011911"
          }
        }
      },
      "r": {},
      "g": null,
      "t": "concessionaria-autorizada"
    }
}
```

```
    private function getFileContent(array $file)
    {
        return json_decode(file_get_contents($file['path']), true)[$file['filename']];
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Neste caso específico** basta você usar o `key` nativo do `php` que ele retornará a primeira chave do seu json.

```
foreach ($files as $file) {
     $data = $this->getFileContent($file);
     $key = key($data); // <-- "suzuki"
```

**Edição**

O problema é que quando você chama a função `getFileContent` ela quebra o json mostrando os dados a partir do array.

```
    json_decode(file_get_contents($file['path']), true)[$file['filename']]; // <-- aqui


    {
      "suzuki": 
      [ // <-- aqui
        {
          "n": "MOTO MAIS",
          "u": "moto-mais",
          "e": { ...
```

Então o indice fica inacessível dentro da função.

**Solução:**

- Primeiro altere a função `getFileContent` para:

  ```
  return json_decode(file_get_contents($file['path']), true);
  ```
- Depois altere a função `fillDealerships` assim:

  ```
  foreach ($files as $file) {
       $data = $this->getFileContent($file);
       $key = $file['filename']; // <-- "suzuki"
       $data = $data[$key]; // <-- array
  ```

Comment: Aqui ele retornou 0

Comment: @RomuloSousa entendi... o seu json já entra formatado na função... Ele começa pelo array. Ou seja, dentro desta função é impossível. Pois a chave não existe dentro dela.

Comment: @RomuloSousa como é lançado o array para a função? Coloque o código na pergunta.

Comment: Adicionei o metodo que ler o arquivo na pergunta.

Comment: @RomuloSousa ja sei... vou editar.

Comment: Porque com esse dado faço o relacionamento entre a concessionaria e a marca.

Comment: @RomuloSousa editado.

Comment: @RomuloSousa deu certo?

Comment: Deu, mas tinha um erro, na minha parte, eu não consigo acessar do seu jeito, está certo, mas por conta do loop, sendo que o nome do arquivo está no `$file['filename`]`.

Ai ele me retorna o nome e o path, mais ai no caso teria que pegar apenas o nome.

```array:2 [
  "filename" => "haojue"
  "path" => "C:\wamp64\www\suzuki-cms-backoffice\database\migrations\production\dealerships\haojue.json"
]```

Comment: @RomuloSousa mas o `$file['filename]` não é "suzuki" ??

Comment: @RomuloSousa tenta do jeito que eu editei... no loop.

Comment: eu fiz assim `  $filename = $file['filename'];` ele me retorna o mesmo que vc :D

Comment: @RomuloSousa retorna suzuki né? Eu tinha escrito errado! =) Coloquei uma edição.

Comment: Suzuki seria o valor que seria pego, está certo.

Comment: Agora estou com um problema em pegar esse dado que serve para vincular o relacionamento entre a concessionaria e marca

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91324/discussion-between-romulo-sousa-and-andrei-coelho).